Using rule-based symbology and cluster point symbology on the same layer?
Working on a tax per acre project for every parcel in Maricopa County, AZ.  For each parcel, symbology is based on the following:

symbol_shape: categorized: land_use_category (SFR, Commercial,
etc)
symbol_color: graduated (RdYlGr): tax_per_acre (0-10,10-20,20-30, etc)
symbol_size: graduated (Flannery: 4.0-80.0): acres (0-500)

Was able to use rule-based symbology to get this working as expected...with one exception, "Multi-Family" like condos with multiple owners on top of one another.  All other property types have one point per parcel where condos may have several points per parcel. Now struggling to figure out how to apply point clustering when land_use_category = "Multi-Family".
Ideally, "Multi-Family" would work as follows (mfc = multi-family cluster):

symbol_shape_mfc: normal symbol and count of parcels clustered
symbol_color_mfc: color should be based on the same graduated tax per
acre scale as all other categories. Tax per acre for a cluster should
be sum of total tax / sum of total acres for all parcels in the
cluster.
symbol_size_mfc: same as above

Is there a way for me to accomplish this without creating a separate layer for multi-family?
If I'm asking the wrong questions and there is better way then that's even better.

One question per Question, please, as per the Tour.
